# ffmpeg: png overlay (Alpha multiply/unmulitply)

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

When I overlay png images in ffmpeg it looks like, that it post-multiplay the alpha channel. For some images it is ok, but I also have images, where I get truth this a dark boarder around the color.

Is it possible to overlay images without a post-multiplied alpha operation in ffmpeg.

Here are my syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -i "image.png" -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay[out]" -map '[out]' -f opengl "test"
```

I think the correct expression would be:

> r/a, g/a, b/a, a

But until now I have not found out how to apply this.

Comment: No this doesn't help. The image comes from Blackmagic Fusion, and there I have a output option "Pre-Divide by Alpha", with this I have no dark boarders. But I can not be sure, that this is always set.

Comment: I think there may be a way to pre-divide with alpha using the blend filter. I'll look into it tomorrow.